# passing id to iframe

Tags: php, mysql

while retrieving from database i have give given an iframe page called(myifp.php).ie

```
while($row=mysql_query($sql)) {
    echo $row['id'];

    <iframe width="523" height="234" scrolling="No"width="500" height="145" src=myifp.php?<?php echo $row['id'];?>" frameborder="0" name="myframe"  ></iframe>
}
```

But the problem That i am getting is when there are multiple rows retrieved from database i am able to retrieve only the last id for all the rows in iframe page(myifp.php).

eg:when there are 5 rows retrieved from db and when i click the first row value,the id remains as 5 itself

..What may be the issue ...plz help me

Comment: You should be actually doing `-echo $row['id']'<iframe widt..'`

Comment: `$row=mysql_query($sql)` does that even work? and there are so many other errors in there....

Comment: @Mr.Alien,Changed the code as You said but The id value still remains in 5 itself for all the retrieved values..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$res=mysql_query($sql)

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    // you got windth and height 2 times here, 1 time is enough
    echo '<iframe width="523" height="234" scrolling="No" width="500" height="145" src="myifp.php?id='.$row['id'].'" frameborder="0" name="myframe"></iframe>';
}
```

Comment: ,changed the code as you said.But still the problem continues

Comment: maybe show more code, like the sql query. because there were like 5 errors in the 4 lines you posted. so guess you have alot more errors in the rest of your code

Comment: i really don't know what you are doing with the code, but my code will put all the different ids into the `src` attributes of the iframes as a GET parameter named `id`. i'm 100% sure on that. if that really doesnt help you, you could put your entire page code to http://pastebin.com/ and post the link. thats the only way i could help you further